# Package and class files access from another project in java

Tags: java, class, package, project

I am currently working on a project. Where I need access to package and class files of another project. I did some research but did not get any final decision.I tried to use this procedure. But it requires the package name in string format and works for same project very well.How can I access packages and class files of another project, where I will only provide the path of the project.Any kind of suggestion will be appreciated. TIA.

```
 Package pkgname = Package.getPackage("packageName");
    List<Class> classesForPackage = getClassesForPackage(pkgname);
    for (Class c : classesForPackage) {
        System.out.println("class name" + c.getName());
        Method[] declaredMethods = c.getDeclaredMethods();
        for (Method method : declaredMethods) {
            System.out.println("method name" + method.getName());
        }
    }
```

Comment: What dependency management system are you using for your project. You can always add the `another` project as a dependency to your `current` project and can access the classes and packages as required.

Comment: Yeah I added the project as a dependency. But I want the list of packages of the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned that you have already added the project as a dependency, I am assuming you already have (or can generate) a `jar` for that project.  You can use the following code to get a list of all the classes and corresponding methods. The method expects absolute path to the jar file :

```
private static void pareseJar(String jarFile) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    JarFile jar = new JarFile(jarFile);
    Enumeration<JarEntry> entries = jar.entries();

    // load the jar
    URL[] urls = { new URL("jar:file:" + jarFile + "!/") };
    URLClassLoader classLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(urls);

    while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
        JarEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
        // if it is a class, load the same and the corresponding methods
        if (entry.getName().endsWith(".class")) {
            String className = entry.getName().replaceAll("/", ".");
            className = className.replace(".class", "");


            Class<?> loadedClass = classLoader.loadClass(className);
            System.out.println("Package Name : " + loadedClass.getPackage().getName());
            System.out.println("Class Name : " + className);

            Method[] methods = loadedClass.getDeclaredMethods();

            for (Method method : methods) {
                System.out.println("    Method Name : " + method.getName());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I executed the same on `commons-codec-1.10.jar` and it results in the following output :

```
Package Name : org.apache.commons.codec.binary
Class Name : org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base32
  Method Name : decode
  Method Name : encode
  Method Name : isInAlphabet

Package Name : org.apache.commons.codec.binary
Class Name : org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
  Method Name : decode
  Method Name : encode
  Method Name : isArrayByteBase64
  Method Name : encodeBase64String
  Method Name : isInAlphabet
  Method Name : isUrlSafe
```

Answer (score 1):

The project is a quite broad concept.

From a class, you don't load a class from a project, but you load a compiled class that is located in the classpath by specifying its full qualified name : package name + className.

It means that if you want to load classes from external projets, these projects should provide their compiled classes in an accessible way for the application that wants to use them.

Packaging the compiled class in a jar is the standard way to do.
The `jar` tool command allows to do it but Maven and Gradle ease strongly the task.
To set the classpath, you can specify the CLASSPATH argument of the `javac` and `java` build command but still once, Maven and Gradle ease strongly the task.

Once the required classes are in the classpath of your application, it should work.